# Does binding a reference actually evaluate the operand?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, undefined-behavior

Consider this code:

```
int& x=*new int;
```

Does RHS of the assignment actually dereference the newly-created pointer, leading to UB due to reading uninitialized variable? Or can this be legitimately used to later assign a value like `x=5;`?

Comment: This is legitimate code and safe as long as you initialize `x` later with some value, rather than consuming the uninitialized variable for some purpose. Better thing would be `int& x = *new int()` which initializes it to Zero value as well. And ofcourse youhave to delete the allocated memory.

Comment: I don't think it's any different from `int y; int& x = y;`, which is what happens by the way when you do `int y; std::cin >> y;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, none of what you've done involves undefined behavior.

It does, however, immediately create a risk of a memory leak. It can be quickly resolved (since `&x` would resolve to the address of the leaked memory, and can therefore be deleted) but if you were to leave scope, you would have no way of retrieving that pointer.

Edit: to the point, if you were to write

```
int& x=*new int;
x = 5;

std::cout << x << std::endl;

std::cin >> x;

std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

The code would behave as though you had simply declared x as `int x;`, except that the pointer would also be left dangling after the program exited scope.

You would achieve undefined behavior if you were to attempt to read the uninitialized variable before assigning it a value, but that wouldn't be untrue if `x` were stack allocated.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Revised the language to say "create a *risk* of a memory leak". And the reason I'm calling it a memory leak in the first place is because on its own, the code itself doesn't contain a user-visible pointer to the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would not advise doing this. Aliasing dynamic memory with a variable that looks static seems dangerous to me. Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int* dynamicAlloc() {
    int& x = *new int;
    std::cout << "Inside dynamicAlloc: " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Modified: " << (x = 1) << std::endl;
    return &x;
}

int main() {
    int *dall = dynamicAlloc();;

    std::cout << "dall (address): " << dall << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dall -> " << *dall << std::endl; // Memory not cleaned

    delete dall; // Don't forget to delete

    return 0;
}
```

I get output like this:

```
Inside dynamicAlloc: -842150451
Modified: 1
dall (address): 00F642A0
dall -> 1
```

Note how dereferencing `dall` doesn't result in a segfault. It wasn't deallocated when x fell out of scope. Otherwise a segfault would have likely occurred.

**In conclusion:**

`int& x` makes x an alias for the dynamically allocated memory. You can legitimately modify that memory, but it will not cleanup as it falls out of scope automatically easily leading to potential memory leaks.

Comment: I don't get this.  Of course you can't use a pointer after it had been deleted.  The only risk for the OP's is if the memory is not handled properly it could leak.

Comment: The main purpose was to demonstrate the address isn't de-allocated after `x` falls out of scope in `test()`. You later could delete `x` if you manage stuff correctly, but it's not intuitive. I'll consider how to re-word once I'm off work

Comment: Hopefully the wording is slightly better now